# Adding mouseover effect to dynamic checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I would like to ask for help on how to implement mouseover to checkbox. What I wan't to achieve is that I want to have mouseover when someone point the cursor to the checkbox based on subject description.

Below is my code to generate dynaminc checkbox but I don;t know how to add mouseover to it. thanks.

```
<?php

$subjects = $stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM subjects");
$stmt->execute();

$cols = 5;

do
{
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $cols; $i++)
    {

        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ($row)
        {
            $sub_id = $row['sub_id'];
            $sub_name = $row['sub_name'];
            $sub_desc = $row['sub_desc']
?>
        <table>
        <tr><td>

        <?php
        echo '<input type="checkbox" sub_id="sub_id[]" name="sub_id[]" value="' . $id_tag . "\"" .'/>' . $tag_name . "\n";
        ?>

        </td></tr>
        </table>

        <?php

        } else {
            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        }
    }
} while ($row);
?>
```

Comment: Can you post your html that is rendered to the browser? PHP code doesn't help with client side problems like creating a hover effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myfn() {
            var myInput = event.target;
            myInput.style.fontSize = "1.2em";
            //some else...
        }
    </script>
    <?php
        echo '<input type="checkbox" onmouseover="myfn();" title="'.$row['sub_desc'].'" sub_id="sub_id[]" name="sub_id[]" value="' . $id_tag . "\"" .'/>' . $tag_name . "\n";
    ?>
```

There's many way to attach events in JavaScript. Another implement is using CSS.

```
<style type="text/css">
input:hover { font-size:1.2em; }
</style>
```

Comment: hi can you provide example on how to show data of $sub_desc = $row['sub_desc']; thanks

Comment: add attribute `title` and its value is `$row['sub_desc']`

Comment: something like var title = $row['sub_desc']; ? sorry im newbie in JS. could you provide code please thanks

Comment: @webdev.gk, I've updated my code in my answer. `$row['sub_desc'] is php code runs on server side, and JavaScript runs on client. you can't mix them up.

Answer (score 3):

When you generate the HTML, you add a CSS class. And then, in your stylesheet, you define a hover effect. Like this:

```
 echo '<input type="checkbox" class="HoverOnCheckbox" sub_id="sub_id[]" name="sub_id[]" value="' 

.HoverOnCheckbox{
  color:green;}

.HoverOnCheckbox:hover{
  color:red;}
```

Comment: thanks guys for suggestion. I can't make it work. I would like to display $sub_desc = $row['sub_desc']; value on the mouse over. can you provide sample code

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() { 
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() { 
    $(this).hover(function(){
     //mouseover effect
  },function(){
    //mouseout effect
  });
});
});
```

EDIT: as @Repox suggested this will work with jquery

Comment: Maybe you should have added that your suggestion requires jQuery.

Comment: @Repox thanks to remind me, i will keep this in my mind,, Thanks a lot to guide me..

Comment: hi can you provide example on how to show data of $sub_desc = $row['sub_desc']; thanks

Comment: @webdev.gk if the matter is to show the data on the mouseover effect then you should have to use .show() effect of the jquery with the above codes, and .hide() effect on mouse out, and by default the check box value is hide, if you prove the html code as well then i will help you more..